# Derivation of the thermal noise spectrum

Tags: quantum-mechanics, thermodynamics, noise

The thermal noise spectrum is given by:
$$\mathcal{S}(f) = \frac{\hbar f}{2(e^{\frac{\hbar f}{kT}} - 1)}$$

This equation seems really similar to the Dirac-Fermi distribution but where does it come from?

Answer (score 1):

This is what I've got so far.

The thermal noise is generated by photons, which follow the Bose-Einstein distribution:
$$N_i = \frac{2}{e^{\epsilon_n/(kT)} - 1}$$
Substituting $E = \omega \hbar$ in the above equation and using that the expected energy is the individual energy of a photon multiplied by the number of photons in that energy level gives:
$$\left< E_i \right> = \frac{2\omega \hbar}{e^{\omega \hbar/(kT)} - 1}$$

Consider a 1D case where the photon is described by the usual wavefunction:
$$\Psi_n(x, t) = A_ne^{j(k_n x - \omega_n t)}$$

In a conductor of length $L$ the boundary conditions are:
$$\Psi_n(0, t) = \Psi_n(L,t) \therefore k_n L=2\pi n$$

The wave velocity in the conductor is:
$$v = \frac{dx}{dt} = \frac{dx}{d \Psi_n} \frac{d\Psi_n}{dt} = \frac{\omega_n}{k_n}$$

The density of states is:
$$\frac{1}{L}dn = \frac{1}{L}\frac{dn}{dk_n}\frac{dk_n}{d\omega_n}d\omega = \frac{1}{L}\frac{L}{2\pi}\frac{1}{v}d\omega = \frac{d\omega}{2\pi v}$$

The energy density can now be calculated by multiplying the density of states by the energy of the individual state:
$$U=\frac{d\omega}{2\pi v} \frac{2\omega \hbar}{e^{\omega \hbar/(kT)} - 1}$$

The energy flow is:
$$P(\omega) = vU=\frac{\omega \hbar}{\pi(e^{\omega \hbar/(kT)} - 1)}d\omega$$

And, finally, changing to frequency using $\omega = 2\pi f$ and $d\omega = 2\pi df$:
$$P(f) = \frac{2hf}{(e^{hf/(kT)} - 1)}df$$

The above quantity needs to be halved because it includes both energy flowing out and in the conductor:
$$P(f) = \frac{hf}{e^{hf/(kT)} - 1}df$$

Thoughts?

Comment: You made a mistake at the line $P=vU$, there is no factor $4$ (supposing here that this is the total flow, out+in), an other mistake at the following line, you have  $(\hbar \omega = h \nu)$, and an other mistake at the last line, where you do not divide by 2, but multiply by 2... So without these mistakes, the final result is correct....So, if you agree, correct the answer, and you will get my +1

Comment: I changed the rest but: $\hbar \omega = \frac{h}{2\pi} 2\pi f = hf$

Comment: Oh Yes... In fact, here is only  one spatial dimension for bosons, so there is only one possible polarization, so you have not the $2$ factor at the beginning.

Comment: It is 2 because of the two circular polarisation photons have.

Comment: I think it is a one-dimensional problem. If it was a $3$-dimensional problem, you would have some $f^3$ in the numerator. So there is only one possible bosonic polarization.

Answer (score 0):

This is one half of the average energy of harmonic oscillator with natural frequency $f$ according to quantum theory when in contact with reservoir with temperature $T$, minus constant $hf/2$.
EDIT: the formula is close the Planck spectrum of thermal fluctuations of EM radiation, and since the latter is everywhere, it may play role in explanation of why electric or other noise has similar spectrum.

Comment: So why would thermal noise have one half of the average energy of harmonic oscillator with natural frequency $f$ according to quantum theory when in contact with reservoir with temperature $T$, minus constant $hf/2$?

Comment: It may not. I just wanted to point out were the formula comes from.